# How to replace values of each cell on a dataframe without looping it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I apply for each cell of my dataframe this conditional (check if I have a string and if its found, replace with a 0) in an easier way?

```
for col in data.columns:
    for day in data.index:
        if (type(data_input_df.loc[day, col]) == 'str'):
            data_input_df[col][day] = 0
```

The data dataframe is:

```
                           Log      1233.de ...      asdad.w.1    fff.op
Tagname                                     ...                        
01/06/2008 00:00            ON      343.04  ...        73.75      79.03
02/06/2008 00:00            ON      332.31  ...        73.71      79.21
03/06/2008 00:00            ON      339.25  ...        75.77      80.11
04/06/2008 00:00            ON      353.25  ...        76.47      79.75
05/06/2008 00:00            ON      353.44  ...        77.35      82.48
```

Which is uploaded as:

```
dat =  pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = 0, index_col = "Tagname")
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First select all columns filled by objects, here because data from `read_csv` are all objects `strings`, create dictionary and set `0` in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.select_dtypes(object).columns, 0)
df = df.assign(**d)

print (df)
                  Log  1233.de  asdad.w.1  fff.op
Tagname                                          
01/06/2008 00:00    0   343.04      73.75   79.03
02/06/2008 00:00    0   332.31      73.71   79.21
03/06/2008 00:00    0   339.25      75.77   80.11
04/06/2008 00:00    0   353.25      76.47   79.75
05/06/2008 00:00    0   353.44      77.35   82.48
```

> What if the dtypes of all columns are all object because of some string appearing in later rows?

Then if not missing values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for convert all columns to numeric with `errors='coerce'` for missing values if not numbers and last only replace all missing values to `0`:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

If possible missing values and need not change them is not possible use `fillna` (because replaced all NaNs), so is used [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with chained tested original data with new one:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').mask(lambda x: x.isna() & df.notna(), 0)
```

Comment: This is not part of the original question, but out of my curiosity; what if the dtypes  of all columns are all `object` because of some string appearing in later rows?

Answer (score 0):

You could coerce the dataframe to numeric datatype then fill NaN with zeroes.

```
df = pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```